# Given a number X, find a number n such that the ceiling of n lg n = X

Tags: c, algorithm, math

I am lost at trying to figure out the formula to give me the right answer for this.

Suppose X = 10, I have to find a number n such that the ceiling is ceiling[n lg n]

So, for X = 10, after trial and error I get 4.56 lg 4.56.

Comment: "trial and error" - write code that does just that...

Comment: If you're looking for a formula, this site isn't the right place at all

Comment: Your example isn't even correct - you're using log base 2, not the natural logarithm.

Comment: I've got a better idea: 1. Ask it on http://math.stackexchange.com/. 2. Implement the code. 3. If you still have any problems, then ask it here again, only this time **enclose your code within the question**.

Comment: The question seems appropriate here under the [math] tag, but showing the actual code would have been better and would also have avoided confusion regarding which base logarithm is used, as Mark Ransom pointed out.

Comment: The problem statement is find n so that ceil(n log2(n) ) = X. This could mean a range of values for n where 9 < n log2(n) <= 10:  4.2863 < n < 4.5649 . Is the goal to find the smallest or largest n ?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in terms of the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). The number you want is log( W(x)), assuming your logarithms are natural.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. However, for x=10, W(x) ~= 1.74553, log(W(z)) ~= 0.557. Could you review your suggested formula?

Comment: @njuffa: I think it should be e**W(X)

Comment: @GregS You are correct: `e**(W(10)) * ln(e^**(W(10)))` results in `10`

Comment: Oops, sorry, exp W(x) it is.

Answer (score 1):

@dmuir was on the correct track, you can use the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) to solve for n * log N = X. Using for example the identity

W(n * log n) = log n

you can derive that n = e<sup>W(X)</sup>.

For X=10, W(X) = 1.745528002, so n = e<sup>1.745528002</sup> = 5.72892556

If, by lg n, you mean the log to the base 2 then the above becomes

n = e<sup>W(X * log(2))</sup> = e<sup>W(X * 0.69314718055)</sup>

Note that the Lambert W function cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. Thus a solution like @Juan Lopes may be just as efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a closed formula for this, but can't you do a simple binary search, like this one?

```
double solve(double a, double b, double x) {
    if (abs(a-b) < 1e-6) return a;
    double n = (a+b)/2;
    if (n*log2(n) > x)
        return solve(a, n, x);
    else
        return solve(n, b, x);
}    

double solve(double x) {
    return solve(0, x, x);
}
```